# Problem using AddIPAddress when impersonating an Admin User

Tags: c++, c, winapi, network-programming

I am attempting to add a temporary IP address to a NIC using AddIPAddress when logged in as a non-admin user. The MSDN documentation for AddIPAddress states that ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE is returned as as error if the function is called by a non-admin user.

Given that I have preceeded the call to AddIPAddress with API calls to LogonUser() and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(). Now my application thinks it's logged in as an Admin, but AddIPAddress still fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

MSDN also states that..

"Note  Group policies, enterprise policies, and other restrictions on the network may prevent these functions from completing successfully. Ensure that the application has the necessary network permissions before attempting to use these functions."

Is it possible to call AddIPAddress using impersonation? if so how? I'm guessing I need to change the permissions mentioned above but I am at a loss as to what to chnage in this area.

Any help would be appreciated!

Additonal: I've also drawn a blank while attempting to call out to netsh (again logged in as a normal user) using CreateProcessAsUser using a handle to an impersonated admin user to launch the process. Always returns errors indicating insufficent priviledges.

Comment: Indeed, tried to get it to work without success. Neither LogonUser/ImpersonateLoggedOnUser nor CoInitializeSecurity helped. Seems like some digging into GpEdit.msc is required.

Comment: Appreciate you taken the time to look into this. I still can't believe it should be so difficult to achieve!

Comment: The relevant configuration seems to be in GpEdit.msc, User configuration, Network, Network connections.  (I'm translating from a German copy of Windows here, so the names might be slightly different.)  Does the code work if you actually run it as Administrator?

Comment: Yes it does work if you run as Admin. In fact that's what I've ended up having to do. It would be nice not to have to tho!

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am developing locally on Windows XP SP2, but the application will need to run on all flavours.

Comment: it appears no one on this entire website can answer this question. This has been here forever.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows Vista you may need to elevate privileges.

In Vista by default [UAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628.aspx) is enabled.  This makes it so that even as an administrator you are using a limited user token unless you explicitly elevate.  When you do this the user is presented with a dialog to allow or deny the request.

For more information on this see [Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx#vistauac_topic6b).

You may want to try using [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(VS.85).aspx) to verify you are properly elevated after you log on as admin.  I would suspect you are getting the limited user token and thus failing requests for privileged resources.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this when I get chance. I have got around the issue by forcing the user to run the app as an admin user. Not what I really wanted but will do for now.
The application will need to run in all flavours of windows.